Use presigned url to reproduce into hls.js
I currently serve videos as follows:
Client:
if (Hls.isSupported()) {
                const hls = new Hls();
                hls.attachMedia(video);
                hls.on(Hls.Events.MEDIA_ATTACHED, function () {
                    hls.loadSource(`/api/videos/getVideo/${video_url}`);
                });
            } else if (video.canPlayType('application/vnd.apple.mpegurl')) {
                // Para iOS y algunos navegadores que soportan HLS nativamente
                video.src = `/api/videos/getVideo/${video_url}`;
            }

/api/videos/getVideo/${video_url}
export async function GET(context: APIContext): Promise<Response> {
    const { video_url } = context.params;

    if (!video_url) return new Response(JSON.stringify({message:"Los campos son requeridos"}), { status: 400 });

    try {
        const response = await fetch(import.meta.env.BUCKET_URL + video_url);
        if (!response.ok)
        return new Response('Video not found', { status: 404 });
        
        const videoStream = response.body;
        const contentType = video_url.endsWith('.m3u8') ? 'application/vnd.apple.mpegurl' : 'application/octet-stream';
        return new Response(videoStream, {
            status:200, 
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': contentType,
                'Cache-Control': 'public, s-maxage=604800, max-age=604800',
                'CDN-Cache-Control': 'public, s-maxage=604800, max-age=604800',
                'Vercel-CDN-Cache-Control': 'public, s-maxage=604800, max-age=604800'
            },
        });
    } catch (error) {
        return new Response('Internal Server Error', { status: 500 });
    }
}

This works correctly but generates a lot of Fast Origin Transfer in Vercel.
I came up with the solution that instead of my website receiving the video from the bucket and delivering it to the client, the hls.js player requests a presigned url of the video from my server and serves the video from that presigned url directly. Is this possible? Would this decrease the Fast Origin Transfer? How would they implement it?
the hls.js player requests a presigned url of the video from my server and serves the video from that presigned url directly. Is this possible? Would this decrease the Fast Origin Transfer? How would they implement it?
